# Unique index values to every element in a python list

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am trying to multiply only certain number in a list with even index number. 
My list has some numbers that occur multiple times. These numbers have the same index values. However, I want to multiply those numbers by 2 only if they occur in the place such that their index number is even.

All forums I searched have the opposite of my need, where they want recurring numbers to have the same index number. 
For my case, I want recurring numbers to have different index values.

```
a = ['2', '0', '0', '1', '4', '5', '6', '4', '0', '4', '6']
my_list = []
for i in a:
    if a.index(i) in [1,3,5,7,9]: 
        #get ascii value using ord()
        a1 = (ord(i)) * 2
    else:
        a1 = ord(i)
        my_list.append(a1)
```

Expected = `[50, 96, 48, 98, 52, 106, 54, 106, 48, 104, 54]`

Got = `[50, 52, 54, 52, 52, 54]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `enumerate` instead of `index`. Also, you can make this a list comprehension:

```
a = ['2', '0', '0', '1', '4', '5', '6', '4', '0', '4', '6']
result = [ord(c) * 2 if i % 2 == 1 else ord(c) for i, c in enumerate(a)]
print(result)
# [50, 96, 48, 98, 52, 106, 54, 104, 48, 104, 54]
```

Loop equivalent:

```
result = []
for i, c in enumerate(a):
    if i % 2 == 1:
         result.append(ord(c) * 2)
    else:
         result.append(ord(c))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are only appending in your else branch

```
a = ['2', '0', '0', '1', '4', '5', '6', '4', '0', '4', '6']
my_list = []
for i in a:
    if a.index(i) in [1,3,5,7,9]: 
        #get ascii value using ord()
        a1 = (ord(i)) * 2
    else:
        a1 = ord(i)
    my_list.append(a1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to add in list for if condition

```
a = ['2', '0', '0', '1', '4', '5', '6', '4', '0', '4', '6']
my_list = []
for i in a:
    if a.index(i) in [1,3,5,7,9]: 
        #get ascii value using ord()
        a1 = (ord(i)) * 2
        my_list.append(a1)
    else:
        a1 = ord(i)
        my_list.append(a1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers got at the fundamental problem (the placement of `append()`), but if you want to be flashy you can do this in a one-line list comprehension:

```
a = ['2', '0', '0', '1', '4', '5', '6', '4', '0', '4', '6']
my_list = [ord(a[i])*2 if i % 2 == 1 else ord(a[i]) for i in range(len(a))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `my_list.append(a1)` to your `if` statement:

```
a = ['2', '0', '0', '1', '4', '5', '6', '4', '0', '4', '6']
my_list = []
for i in a:
    if a.index(i) in [1,3,5,7,9]: 
        #get ascii value using ord()
        a1 = (ord(i)) * 2
        my_list.append(a1)
    else:
        a1 = ord(i)
        my_list.append(a1)
```

Or better, just execute it after the `else`:

```
a = ['2', '0', '0', '1', '4', '5', '6', '4', '0', '4', '6']
my_list = []
for i in a:
    if a.index(i) in [1,3,5,7,9]: 
        #get ascii value using ord()
        a1 = (ord(i)) * 2
    else:
        a1 = ord(i)
    my_list.append(a1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems here.  As others have mentioned, you need to move the `append` outside of the else branch.  You are also discarding the current index of the list element as you loop through it, which you then look up with `a.index(i)`--this won't give the correct result in the case of repeated elements because it will return the index of the *first* match.  You could e.g. use the `enumerate` function to get both the index and the element in the loop.

```
a = ['2', '0', '0', '1', '4', '5', '6', '4', '0', '4', '6']
my_list = []
for idx, i in enumerate(a):
    if idx in [1,3,5,7,9]: 
        #get ascii value using ord()
        a1 = (ord(i)) * 2
    else:
        a1 = ord(i)
    my_list.append(a1)
```